# Magento Pull in addresses from separate database table to save under customer data when account created

Tags: php, magento

I have an extra field in my customer account registration where the customer can choose a US school from our database that they are affiliated with. We want to have the school address populated into the customer data when the customer account is created.

I have turned on address fields in customer account creation via the following xml in local.xml. I temporarily have the fields commented out in the register.phtml template. I am going to post the address this way, but if there is more than one address I would like to add to the customer account, how would I add more during the registration post?

```
<customer_account_create>
        <reference name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
        </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

Going to do an ajax call to obtain the school address then append the applicable values in the following hidden fields. Again, I will often need to post more than one address.

```
<?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="create_address" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="company" id="company" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="street[]" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="street[]" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address 2') ?>" id="street_2" />
        <input type="hidden" name="city" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" id="city" />
        <input type="hidden" id="region_customer_id" name="region_cait_id" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="region" name="region" value="" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
        <input type="hidden" name="postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getPostcode()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" id="zip" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**If I need to create a module instead:** What event should I hook into? How do I save an address into customer data? I will need values posted on the customer account creation form.

Comment: I wouldn't populate the hidden fields with data.  Instead, extend the account creation model to determine the id of the school selected.  Using the school_id, obtain the address information, load it into the address model and save it.

Comment: Huh? No ... ugh I'm probably making it sound more complicated .I am simply just trying to add school addresses to the customer's address book. I already have a custom dropdown on registration to choose a school, but sometimes they could be a district purchaser which means I have to save several school addresses

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do.  You need to extend the customer model to read the school the user picks (at account creation), then create an address record for that customer using the school's information.

Comment: I agree with Axel. Do this programatically in the model by extending it of course into your own module. Allow the user to choose the school from dropdown and register as normal. When the data gets posted, pick up the school id, lookup all the addresses from your database, and assign new addresses to the account that has just been created.

Comment: Ah I see what you both are saying. What classes am I extending?

Answer (score 0):

The Event To pullout

```
customer_register_success event
```

[Create an event As in SITE](http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105)

Comment: And how do I save the addresses to the customer? How do I obtain the id of the customer that just registered?

Comment: $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer() ?

Comment: NVM all of this. I've got it

Comment: I will post the whole module. :)